# Using grep to get the count of files where keyword exist

Tags: grep

I am trying to get the count of files which has matching keywords in directory. Code I used is:

`grep -r -i --include=*.sas 'keyword'` - This gives the total count of keyword.

`grep -l "keyword" --include="*.sas" * | wc -l` -  this code is not working.

Can any one help me to, how to get the count of the files which contains the keyword.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "is not working"? Do you actually want a subdirectory search (as implied by the `-r` in your first command) or only the top level directory (as implied by the `*` wildcard in your second command)?

Answer (score 4):

I would personally use `find` together with `grep` to do this counting:

```
find . -type f -name '*.sas' -exec grep -q -e 'pattern' {} \; -exec echo x \; |
wc -l
```

Add `-maxdepth 1` before the first `-exec` if you don't want `find` to recurse into subdirectories.

What this does is to run `grep -q -e 'pattern'` on each file with a `.sas` filename suffix in the current directory or below.  For each file wherein `pattern` matches, an `x` will be outputted by `echo x`.  The number of lines outputted by `echo` in this way is then counted by `wc -l`.  We count `x`es instead of filenames with `wc` since filenames may contain newline characters.

For a non-recursive variant of this, you may also opt for a simple shell loop:

```bsh
for name in ./*.sas; do
    [ ! -f "$name" ] && continue
    grep -q -e 'pattern' "$name" && echo x
done | wc -l
```

or,

```bsh
n=0
for name in ./*.sas; do
    [ ! -f "$name" ] && continue
    grep -q -e 'pattern' "$name" && n=$((n + 1))
done
echo "$n"
```

If your `pattern` is not a regular expression but a string, use `grep -q -F -e 'string'` instead.

Comment: with `find` implementations supporting `-printf` option, you don't need to call `echo`.

Comment: @pLumo That's true. My native `find` on OpenBSD does not have `-printf`.

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
find $DIR  -type f  -name '*.sas'  -exec grep -m1 -e 'pattern' {} \; | wc -l
```

With the -m1 option, `grep` will output at most 1 line per file, so that way the `wc -l` will give you the correct number of files which contained that pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any way i can get information about the number unique .sas files in subfolder also which contain this pattern. like Folder 1 - 23 .sas files | folder2 - 56 .sas files

Comment: Yes, the above command does exactly that -- gives the total count of such files in $DIR and all its subfolders. But if you want to limit the count to only the $DIR folder, then add a `-maxdepth 1` before the  `-exec`.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -rl --include='*.sas' keyword . | wc -l
```

Would work as long as file paths don't contain newline characters.

To work with those, you'd need to switch to NUL-delimited records instead of lines:

```
grep -rlZ --include='*.sas' keyword . | tr -cd '\0' | wc -c
```

(note that `-r`/`-Z`/`--include` are non-standard extensions and `*.sas` would fail to match on filenames that contain sequences of bytes not forming valid characters in the locale (like a `$'st\xe9phane.sas'` in a UTF-8 locale)).

Answer (score 2):

```
\grep -rh -i -m1 --include='*.sas' -e 'pattern' |wc -l
```

`-h`: don't output filename. will not break then on file/path containing newline.
`-m1`: stop reading the rest of the file once first match found
`-r`: recursive
`-i`: case insensitive match
`-e`: use PATTERN as a *pattern*; avoid treating `-` as grep switch identifier if it come at the beginning of the pattern.

---

There is also an answer of mine on AU, that I think it's useful to take a look and use it for quick review on each switch you want to know about it instead of looking/scrolling from `man grep`:

- [How to use grep to search for options in a man page?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1281460/283843)